# How can I make a window modal in a Catalyst app?

Tags: ios, swift, mac-catalyst

Is there any way to make a window run as modal in a Mac Catalyst app?
I have tried everything I could think of, including:

- Detecting a window resigning key and calling `makeKey` on it again. Doesn't work.
- Changing the `windowLevel` of the window. No effect.
- Detecting when a window scene is not key and calling `UIApplication.shared.requestSceneSessionActivation` on that session. This one kind of works but I need to delay the call, which means the window is not key for a brief moment, and it also feels glitchy afterwards.
- Using a Mac plugin to run `NSApplication.shared.runModal(for: window)` and `NSApplication.shared.stopModal()`. This one does make the window modal but it looks like it breaks some of the actions in the window, buttons stop working.